# How to commit all transactions in sql server?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

i need to commit all transactions at a time to DB.what is procedure for that?
Store the requests from each user in a queue after commit all tranasactions on to the backend DB.
Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

EDIT:

```
1.Run the update query for each user to add data to table.
2.Run the session for n users(10 users).
3.Store the requests from each user in a queue.
4.after commit all trnasactions on to backend DB at a time.
```

Comment: Your question lacks some information and can't be appropriatelly answered.
Does each of your users open separate session or everything is controlled from same session? What kind of queue are you using (Service Broker)? Is there only one database (your 'backend DB')?

Comment: same session will be for all users.only one database in that we are having one table need to update that .

Comment: see proposed answer...

Answer (score 4):

You can simply fire `commit` command , if you are using transactions in SQL.

You can also use [Autocommit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187878%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to automatically commit the transaction when it is finished. This will not let you to fire commit command.

You can find all the uncommited transactions through `DBCC opentran;` command.

Comment: Are you sure you can commit tansactions that are not part of the current session that way?

Comment: @Serge You could probably do some silly things with the (deprecated) `sp_bindsession` to force those transactions to commit...

Comment: also provided option of autocommit.

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple sessions, you'd have to somehow queue your user related operations and execute them inside same transaction (using begin/commit transaction).

If you have one session then there is probably enumerated resource you are using to start your insert/update for eash user item - that may be your users table. If your data modifying requirement is simple enough, you could write it in one command and it will be executed in same transaction. Otherwise you could use notorious cursors to loop thru user related items and exec commands one by one. Of course, you should wrap that with begin/commit tran.